# Looping facter_disks in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to loop thru facter_disks to find disk with a particular size. In the below code would like to get disk sdb with size of 30 . Any help is greatly appreciated

```
---
- name: sample Playbook
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: yes
  vars:
    disks:
      - sda:
          model: SYMMETRIX
          size: 55.00 GiB
          size_bytes: 59057111040
          vendor: EMC
        sdb:
          model: SYMMETRIX
          size: 35.00 GiB
          size_bytes: 37581619200
          vendor: EMC
        sdc:
          model: SYMMETRIX
          size: 20.00 GiB
          size_bytes: 21475491840
          vendor: EMC


  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg:
#         - "{{ disks[0]['sda']['size'] }}"
          - "{{ item['sda']['size'] }}"
      with_items: " {{disks}} "
```

Comment: Question: why would you manually set the vars? As Ansible can gather the facts from the host itself, which would make more sense to use.

Comment: I was manually setting it just for testing .  ansible gather_facts  lists facter_disks in the same format does not put list for each disk and so i have am difficulty trying to loop thru the disks.

Comment: You should solve that, instead of manually setting variables, which is a bad practice.

Comment: Sorry don't get it . facter_disk is in this format . I cannot change it.  I am trying to loop thru facter_disks  that ansible gather_facts collects about the system.

Comment: you are missing `-` infront of `sdb` and `sdc` in your `vars` declaration

Answer (score 0):

disks var is a list then you need to use "-" before sda, sdb, sdc. In this case if you want to use disks as a list of disks then you can modify and set a name property as I write below

```
---
- name: sample Playbook
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: yes
  vars:
    disks:
    - name: sda
      model: SYMMETRIX
      size: 55.00 GiB
      size_bytes: 59057111040
      vendor: EMC
    - name: sdb
      model: SYMMETRIX
      size: 35.00 GiB
      size_bytes: 37581619200
      vendor: EMC
    - name: sdc
      model: SYMMETRIX
      size: 20.00 GiB
      size_bytes: 21475491840
      vendor: EMC

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
        - "{{ item.name }}"
        - "{{ item.model }}"
        - "{{ item.size }}"
        - "{{ item.size_bytes }}"
        - "{{ item.vendor }}"
      with_items: " {{disks}}"
      when: item.size == "35.00 GiB"
```

Comment: Ansible factor (gather_facts ) generates the facter information in the same format so trying to loop thru the disks.  disks sda ,sdb, etc are not  individual list items .